# How can a black hole be a cause of a Big Bang?

Tags: black-holes, nuclear-physics

Is it possible that Big Bang occurred as a result of the black hole formation - that is the matter compressed so densely that it "exploded" within the boundaries of its horizon and became a what we call the "Big Bang"?

Comment: I might be hugely simplifying and make this very crude, not to mention that it might be obviously wrong. Pardon me as I am not physicist. If the idea is preposterous I would like someone to point out why. Thanks very much

Comment: @ACuriousMind, and others please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the event horizon, gravity is so strong that light itself cannot get away from the black hole. Inside the event horizon, gravity is even stronger. It's important to note that nothing about GR forbids dynamics according to the other three forces of nature within the black hole, but even so, gravity is so strong that the particles inside cannot fly away from each other in any way significant enough that it would probably fit your notion of an "explosion."

It's also worth noting that there are three black-hole solutions to GR: the Schwarzschild, Kerr, and Reissner-Nordstroem solutions, and none of them addresses the dynamics of any material singularity, or even of how black holes actually form - they are static solutions.

EDIT: While we're at it, let's also point out that atomic bombs do not explode simply because the fissile matter is compressed - that is simply necessary to increase the likelihood of the nuclear reactions that release a bunch of energy, and it is this release of energy that causes / constitutes the explosion. Simply compressing any arbitrary matter will not necessarily cause an explosion.

Comment: Just to clarify - my definition of explosion would be "Big Bang". Apologies, I made it very unclear and I am not educated in this field. Do you think it is not too late to rephrase my question into: "Is a black hole a cause of a Big Bang?" Thanks, appreciate your time.

Comment: @datageek the Big Bang wasn't an explosion, and none of the concepts that specifically explain a nuclear explosion are even relevant for the Big Bang or vice versa. I suggest you roll back your edit and post your new question separately, since as it is the edit invalidates an otherwise correct answer.